# problem to stack() and unstack() with python pandas 2.1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data frame df:

```
               (O0, O, 0.66)  (H1, H, 0.31)  (H2, H, 0.31)
(O0, O, 0.66)            NaN            NaN            NaN
(H1, H, 0.31)       0.957897            NaN            NaN
(H2, H, 0.31)       0.957897         1.5109            NaN
```

Can't be stack with `df.stack(future_stack=True)`. It gives the following error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['O0'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

df ist generated with:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(xyz_df.iloc[:,3:6],'euclid')),
              columns = xyz_df[['atom1_idx','element','cov_radius']],
              index = xyz_df[['atom2_idx','element','cov_radius']])
```

Note: `xyz_df.iloc[:,3:6]` contains atomic coordinates; `squareform...` (from scipy) for the calculation of a distance matrix

With `df.stack(future_stack=False).dropna()` it seems okay:

```
(H1, H, 0.31)  (O0, O, 0.66)    0.957897
(H2, H, 0.31)  (O0, O, 0.66)    0.957897
               (H1, H, 0.31)    1.510900
```

`df.unstack()` gives the same error message.

In the end I would like to have something like:

```
               level_1        0
(H1, H, 0.31)  (O0, O, 0.66)  0.957897
(H2, H, 0.31)  (O0, O, 0.66)  0.957897
(H2, H, 0.31)  (H1, H, 0.31)  1.510900
```

It simply works with pandas 1.5.3, but no longer with 2.1.0. It seems that the problem arises from the format of the indexes and the columns. Is there a way to handle this in pandas 2.1.0 (and higher)? Thank you!

The following code is related and gives the same error:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

c_1 = 'A0', 'B0', 0.11
c_2 = 'A1', 'B1', 0.12
c_3 = 'A2', 'B2', 0.14
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns= [c_1,c_2,c_3], index = ['(i1, i2, i3)','(i4, i5, i6)','(i7, i8, i9)'])
print(df)
#okay
print(df.stack(future_stack=False))
print(df.unstack())
# error:
print(df.stack(future_stack=True))
```

Addendum:
Actually I think this is a bug or a completely different behavior. So, I opened an "Issue" on GitHub. I'll will also report here about the outcome.

Addendum:
Yes, it is a bug. Will probably be fixed in 2.1.1: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54948

Comment: Can you provide a constructor for the input?

Comment: ``
dist_mat_full=pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(xyz_df.iloc[:,3:6],'euclid')),
     columns = xyz_df[['atom1_idx','element','cov_radius']],
     index = xyz_df[['atom2_idx','element','cov_radius']])
`` I hope this is okay. It shows how the indexes and columns are generated.

Comment: Please add additional information inline in your question rather than in comments.